# awk capture text inside html tags and remove other within other tags

Tags: html, linux, bash, awk

I am quite new in awk, and learning already. I have html text that I want to process just by command line linux. I am trying with AWK, which seems the perfect tool for this.

What I want is to extract text inside  including the body tags. And also remove  content.

Thanks

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, no. Awk is a good tool for plain text, not for structured data such as HTML. Especially not for HTML, which is about the quirkiest structured data format you can find. What you want to look into is something like python's [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html).

Comment: I know about python parser like Beautiful Soup, lxml, etc, but I want to do in one line. I don't want to mantain python files or projects. Also I want a fast process with low footprint.

Comment: @iwxfer: You can use `xmllint` with a `html` parsable flags, but you can start by providing your input file and the output you need out of it.

Comment: @Wintermute GNU awks [XML parser](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawkextlib) isn't a bad option for structured data such as HTML.

Comment: @EdMorton That's an interesting extension, but does it work on HTML? It's based on expat, which I believe parses strictly XML.

Comment: @Wintermute I assume it does but I haven't tried it, for all I do with XML or HTML a simple hack with normal awk works just fine.